# react-native-gifted-chat Guidance on input, action sheet and emoji picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am developing a react-native/expo/firebase chat application for intellectually impaired individuals using gifted-chat. I have the chat app working for typical users. My next step is to provide the ability to send various messages containing spoken text, videos and, most importantly, AAC symbols. I want to treat the AAC symbols like emojis

I'm having a difficult time understanding how to do this with gifted chat.

The behavior I'm looking for is to have the accessory bar have an aac icon that when tapped, surfaces an emoji like component under the input component, sliding the input component up. I also want an activity sheet for more complex message creation (including also selecting the AAC emojis).

I assume I can hide and show the emoji picker as necessary, but I'm confused as to how to slide the input control up when visible. Also, I have a renderActions renderer set but I thought if that was set, a "default" action sheet would be shown. Tapping it does nothing, however.

Do I need an custom input toolbar? Do I need to create a custom action sheet (I will eventually but I was hoping to see the default one working first).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.